# Xero API GET Payments not returning results with line items, even with pagination

Tags: xero-api

I tried the following request:

```
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments?page=1
```

to try and get all payments with the line items, however the line items list is empty for all records in that page and subsequent pages. The line items are appearing when looking at payments at an individual level however looping over each payment ID is not feasible method to extract a large number of records especially with api call limits. Is there any way to force the full data to be shown?